# The image added to the Fabricjs canvas is not editable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend, fabricjs

I'm trying to develop an application using fabricjs in Reactjs. I want to upload an image to the site and then when this uploaded image is clicked, it will be added to the canvas and can be edited (moved and resized). But I couldn't solve the problem. While the image can be edited where I show it with a red arrow, I cannot interact with it where I show it with a blue arrow.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZChD.png)

I tried to solve the problem by adding a direct link to the image myself, but I was not successful. I looked at a lot of sites but couldn't find a solution.

```js
// ImageUploader.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

const ImageUploader = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState(null);

  const onDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
    // Add the uploaded files to the images state
    setImages((prevImages) => [...prevImages, ...acceptedFiles]);
  };

  const handleImageClick = (image) => {
    // Add the clicked image to the Fabric.js canvas
    if (canvas) {
      fabric.Image.fromURL(URL.createObjectURL(image), (img) => {
        img.set({
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          scaleX: 1,
          scaleY: 1,
        });
        canvas.add(img);
      });
    }
  };

  const initializeCanvas = () => {
    const newCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric-canvas', {
      backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
      selection: false, // Disable Fabric.js built-in selection for better control
    });
    setCanvas(newCanvas);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initializeCanvas();
  }, []); // Initialize canvas on component mount

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    accept: 'image/*', // Allow only image files
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div {...getRootProps()} style={dropzoneStyles}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        {isDragActive ? (
          <p>Drop the images here...</p>
        ) : (
          <p>Drag 'n' drop some images here, or click to select files</p>
        )}
      </div>
      {images.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <h2>Uploaded Images</h2>
          <ul>
            {images.map((image, index) => (
              <li key={index} onClick={() => handleImageClick(image)} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                <img
                  src={URL.createObjectURL(image)}
                  alt={`Uploaded ${index + 1}`}
                  style={{ maxWidth: '100px', maxHeight: '100px', margin: '5px' }}
                />
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
      <div>
        <h2>Fabric.js Canvas</h2>
        <canvas id="fabric-canvas" width={500} height={500} style={{ border: '1px solid #ccc' }} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const dropzoneStyles = {
  border: '2px dashed #cccccc',
  borderRadius: '4px',
  padding: '20px',
  textAlign: 'center',
  cursor: 'pointer',
};

export default ImageUploader;
```

Comment: it's probably something you've done wrong in your code

Comment: I forgot the add code  I'll add it when I am avaliable